# Joomla – Local Site is Not Showing Same from Hosting Site

Tags: git, joomla, localhost, hosting, clone

I was looking everywhere and I found no luck but post a question in here.  Please understand and bear with me that I’m still learning Joomla!. I wanted to work on my locahost instead work on hosting server.  I successfully implemented the git on hosting server and able to created a repository.

I cloned this repository to my local machine in htdocs in MAMP folder.  I installed Joomla from https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5655-joomla-3-5-1-released.html then I copied only installation folder into cloned folder.

I imported the database where I export it from hosting server into my phpmyadmin in localhost.

Then, I went to a localhost site and I filled out the correct requirements: name of database, user, and password, etc.  Once it was done, I removed the installation folder and went to landing page (Sample A); however, it showed white background and startup site instead showing similar to my hosting site (Sample B).

I rechecked the configuration.php in several times to make sure it’s configured correctly and it still showed the same issue’s result.

Please help and solve my issue and I know there must be something a simple solution for this issue.

Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's difficult to move a site the way you describe, there's plenty of potential for something not working.

You could try checking $host and $live_site in the configuration.php file of your MAMP installation, the following settings are probably what you want.

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $live_site = '';
```

If you don't have any success with the above, have you considered using [Akeeba backup](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup/)?

You would make a backup on your hosting server, download that backup to your MAMP directory, and use [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) to unpack the backup. After that the installation process is similar to installing a fresh copy of Joomla.

Akeeba backup will solve almost all your hassles when moving from one server to another, or one domain to another.

Good luck!